# display data in table from given string of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have to display data in html table in **value** column from given textarea field. The string value should be converted into an array and all data will execute through loop and display by sequence of order.
[image: Image to illustrate]

input string : `vivek purohit abc xyz` (and string data should be display sequence vise in value column)

here is my html code & javascript code:

```js
function getValue() {
var data = document.getElementById("value").value;
    var res = data.split(" ");
    console.log(res);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    var store= [];
    var dta = '<table><tr><td>Value</td><tr></table>'
        for( i=1;i<=53;i++){
            
            store += dta;
        }
        document.getElementById("dta").innerHTML = store;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flight Data</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table,
        td,
        th {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <textarea id="value" name="value" rows="" cols=""></textarea>
    <button type="submit" onclick="getValue()">Submit</button>
    <!-- <p id="demo"></p> -->
    <h2 id="demo"></h2>
    <h2 id="s1"></h2>
    <div id="dta"></div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th> Sr No.</th>
            <th>ASDI</th>
            <th>Aerobook</th>
            <th id='value'>Value</th>
                   
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Message Type</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Aircraft identifier</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Aircraft data</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Coordination fix</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Coordination time</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Entry Point Name</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>Entry Point Time</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>Exit Point Name</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>Exit Point Time</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Route</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Departure point</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>Final destination</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>Actual Arrival time</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>Registration</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>Allocated SSR code</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>SSR Equipment</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>Aircraft Com/Nav/App aid Equipment.</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>Remarks field</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>Code field</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>Operator field</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>Scheduled departure time.</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>Actual departure time</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>Estimated time of arrival as filed</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>ADES 1 (Destination airport at activation)</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>Number of missed approaches at ADES 1</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>Time diverted from ADES 1</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>ADES 2 (First diversion airport)</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>Number of missed approaches at ADES 2</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>Time diverted from ADES 2</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>30</td>
             <td>ADES 3 (Second diversion airport).</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>31</td>
             <td>Number of missed approaches at ADES 3</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>32</td>
             <td>Time diverted from ADES 3.</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>33</td>
             <td>Number of instrument approaches.</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>34</td>
             <td>Number of local movements.</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>35</td>
             <td>Persons on board</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>36</td>
             <td>Returned field.</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>37</td>
             <td>Touched-down field.</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>38</td>
             <td>ICAO flight type and AFL billing ancillary flight type.</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>39</td>
             <td>Filed Flight Rules.</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>40</td>
             <td>Final Flight Rules.</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>41</td>
             <td>Distance to run at change to final flight rules.</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>42</td>
             <td>Time of change to final flight rules.</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>43</td>
             <td>SPA name at change to final flight rules.</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>44</td>
            <td>Route type indicator</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>Route miles flown</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>Departure airport runway.</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>Final destination airport runway</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>Termination agent.</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>49</td>
            <td>Termination time</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>Deletion agent</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>Landing Gate</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>52</td>
            <td>Departure Gate</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>Activation message time stamp</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you clarify, please, what you are trying to do here. As it stands the `getValue` function appears to generate 53 html tables and insert them all into a single div. Why 53? Will there be many items in the textarea that will become the `value`???

Comment: Incidentally you declare `store` as an array and then treat it like a string. `var store='';` would be more appropriate than `var store=[];`